# PostGIS/QGIS visualization with strange characters in attribute table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, attribute-table

I loaded a shapefile into a PostGIS database. When I visualized it in QGIS I noticed that in the attribute table, some fields with integer data type, are displayed in a strange form.

However when I save the data as shapefile the fields look normal.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Can you check and specify data types and precision for both tables?

Comment: The notation in the first image is a variation on scientific notation. The e stands for exponent. `3,86589e+07` is the same as `3,86589 x 10^07` (3,86589 times 10 to the seventh power).

Comment: i loaded a set of shapefiles whit long data type and precision 9 after that , merge them into a single table.

when i check the table properties in postgis they apear as integer without specified precision.

then when i save them as shapefile they appear as  double whit 10.

anyway i tried whit a early version of qgis (beacause i was using Qgis 3) and now the fields shows in normal way (whit 2.18 version)